# How to add values from one viewmodel to another viewmodel in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 lists in from the `MainVM` view model, I would like if by iterating through these 2 lists the values can be extracted and added to the other list from the `DescRecordsVM` view model.

To give an example of what I want to do is iterate the `Attachments` list and save the values to `Records` and then iterate the `Emails` list and save it to `Records` as well.

```
Attachments                         Records
ID = 5                             --> ID=5
documentName = "file.pdf"          --> Description = "file.pdf"
dpcumentType="PDF"                 --> Type="PDF"

Emails                                 Records
ID = 7                               --> ID=7
EmailName = "Progress"               --> Description = "Progress"
dpcumentType="GMAIL"                 --> Type="GMAIL"
```

I wanted to know if this is possible to do if you can give me how the code can be to do this in a method to return the Records View model or is there another way to do it?

Main view models:

```
public class MainVM
{
    public List<AttachmentVM> Attachments { get; set; }
    public List<EmailVM> Emails{ get; set; }
}

public class AttachmentVM
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string documentName { get; set; }
    public string documentType { get; set; }
}

public class EmailVM
{
    public Guid Id { get; set;  }
    public string EmailName{ get; set; }
    public string EmailType { get; set; }
}
```

New view model

```
public class DescRecordsVM
{
    public List<DescriptionVM> Records { get; set; }
}

public class DescriptionVM
{
    public Guid Id { get; set;  }
    public string Description{ get; set; }
    public string Type{ get; set; }
}
```

The controller receives the ID fills the lists from the database.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetCommunications(long id )
{
    var vm = new ViewModels.MainVM();
    vm.Attachments = GetAttachments(id).ToList();
    vm.Emails= GetAttachments(id).ToList();

    // This is where my idea is to iterate through each list 
    // and fill the `Records` list from `DescRecordsVM` 
    // view model with the values.

    return PartialView("view",Records);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your *AttachmentVM* and *EmailVM* using Select method.

```
var attachmentRecords = vm.Attachments.Select(a => new DescriptionVM
{
    Id = a.Id,
    Description = a.documentName,
    Type = a.documentType
});

var emailRecords = vm.Emails.Select(a => new DescriptionVM
{
    Id = a.Id,
    Description = a.EmailName,
    Type = a.EmailType
});

var records = attachmentRecords.Concat(emailRecords);
```

Comment: Thank you Netan !! I think it will work, do you know how this "var= recods" can I add the values of it to this list:    List<DescriptionVM> Records { get; set; }

Comment: Depending how you create DescRecordsVM or where you store it reference.
`var descVM = new ViewModels.DescRecordsVM(); descVM.Records = attachmentRecords.Concat(emailRecords).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood correctly.You want to add all the elements(AttachmentVM,EmailVM) inside this to the record class(DescriptionVM).I did this with AutoMapper

Nuget package:
1.AutoMapper 2.AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection

Controller:

```
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        public HomeController(IMapper mapper)
        {
            _mapper = mapper;
        }
```

Action

```
 var DescriptionVMViewModel = _mapper.Map<List<DescriptionVM>>(vm.Attachments);
 var EmailVMViewModel = _mapper.Map<List<DescriptionVM>>(vm.Emails);
  DescRecordsVM _DescRecordsVM = new DescRecordsVM();
  _DescRecordsVM.Records = new List<DescriptionVM>();
  _DescRecordsVM.Records.AddRange(DescriptionVMViewModel);
```

Program:

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));
// Auto Mapper Configurations
var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
{
    mc.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
});
IMapper mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(mapper);
```

Mapping

```
  public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<AttachmentVM, DescriptionVM>()
        .ForMember(dest =>
            dest.Id,
            opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
        .ForMember(dest =>
            dest.Description,
            opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.documentName))
          .ForMember(dest =>
            dest.Type,
            opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.documentType));
            CreateMap<EmailVM, DescriptionVM>()
      .ForMember(dest =>
          dest.Id,
          opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
      .ForMember(dest =>
          dest.Description,
          opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EmailName))
        .ForMember(dest =>
          dest.Type,
          opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EmailType));
        }
    }
```

example data:

```
 List<AttachmentVM> GetAttachments(Guid Id)
        {
            List<AttachmentVM> vMs = new List<AttachmentVM>();
            AttachmentVM attachment = new AttachmentVM();
            attachment.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            attachment.documentName = "ddd";
            attachment.documentType = "tee";
            vMs.Add(attachment);
            attachment = new AttachmentVM();
            attachment.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            attachment.documentName = "sdsd";
            attachment.documentType = "sdsd";
            vMs.Add(attachment);
            return vMs;
        }
        List<EmailVM> GetEmails(Guid Id)
        {
            List<EmailVM> vMs = new List<EmailVM>();
            EmailVM attachment = new EmailVM();
            attachment.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            attachment.EmailName = "tete";
            attachment.EmailType = "s";
            vMs.Add(attachment);
            attachment = new EmailVM();
            attachment.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            attachment.EmailName = "ssdsdddsd";
            attachment.EmailType = "sds";
            vMs.Add(attachment);
            return vMs;
        }
```

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core